# Reason for calling an instance method on a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to know is there any specific reason for doing this or is this a silly mistake done by someone (or is it something else that I am not understanding).

```
class SomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def first_method(user)
    mail(to: user.email, subject: "Testing")
  end
end
```

This method is called at some other place in the code as follows

```
SomeMailer.first_method(user).deliver
```

Comment: `mail()` returns a Message instance, so `deliver()` is triggered on that instance, not on the `SomeMailer` class, see https://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/mail - `[...] and return a fully prepared Mail::Message ready to call :deliver on to send`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionMailer::Base` classes are weird... Yes, you do indeed call instance methods on the class - which obviously won't work for 'normal' classes!

But there's [some meta-programming magic under the hood](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2efddadd6cba4e2129acedf1d402d11abcc03996/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L561-L567):

```
module ActionMailer
  class Base < AbstractController::Base
    def method_missing(method_name, *args) # :nodoc:
      if action_methods.include?(method_name.to_s)
        MessageDelivery.new(self, method_name, *args)
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you look through [the rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), you'll see that calling instance methods on the class is, strangely, the normal thing to do for mailers.

Answer (score 1):

This is how rails is intended to work.
It is also mention in rails guides that

> You never instantiate your mailer class. Rather, you just call the method you defined on the class itself.

Rails do the internal processing by invoking `method_missin`.
Basically, any action method defined in mailer class will be intercepted by method_missing and will return an instance of MessageDelivery, otherwise it runs the default implementation. And where do action methods come from? ActionMailer::Base inherits from AbstractController::Base, so it works exactly the same as for controllers - it returns a set of public instance methods of a given class.

Rails itself encourage this behavior. For more information, you can refer this [link](https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/07/31/decoding-rails-magic-how-does-calling-class-methods-on-mailers-work/)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this since I have come across similar situations myself while working on existing code.

The instance methods like this in a class help when you do **call backs** on a class. For example, if you want to perform some action on a object that was created from that class.

Say you have another class **User** and you want to send an email to a user immediately after creating a new user. In that case you can call this method on that object by doing

`after_save :method_name`